# Android Room Persistence library entity with AutoValue

Tags: android, android-room, auto-value

Is it possible to use both [Room persistence library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)'s `@Entity` with [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value)'s `@AutoValue` and builder on the same POJO? How should i do it?

Comment: I ran into problems with this and [filed this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62408420), so AFAIK as of `1.0.0-alpha3` this is still not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. if you post it as answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Added comment in the feature request, @CommonsWare did you get any news about it other than the comments in the feature request ?

Comment: @JoseF: No, sorry.

Comment: I see that it was upgraded from Priorty 3 to Priority 2 on Nov. 28, 2017

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AFAIK, as of `1.0.0-alpha3`, this is not possible. Room wants fields; AutoValue doesn't expose fields. Keep tabs on [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62408420) for progress in this area.

Answer (score 6):

This feature will be available in Room 2.1.0
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62408420#comment27

Answer (score 1):

Released in 2.1.0-alpha01!

Note that you have to add the @CopyAnnotations annotation for it to work

> Auto Value: Room now supports declaring AutoValue annotated classes as entities and POJOs. The Room annotations @PrimaryKey, @ColumnInfo, @Embedded and @Relation can now be declared in an auto value annotated class’ abstract methods. Note that these annotation must also be accompanied by @CopyAnnotations for Room to properly understand them.

[see the release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Following this task, apparently they added support. I assume it will be possible in the future Room release (probably androidx.room version 2.0.0).
Still not merged as part of 2.0.0-beta1 though

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible with the Room database 2.1.0.

You can make this possible by annotating the abstract class methods with @PrimaryKey, @ColumnInfo, @Embedded, and @Relation. The abstract class has to be annotated with @Autovalue.