# Joining tables in a ROOM database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-database

This is my first ROOM implementation. I have a **User** class which has a list of **Pets** as one of its member variables.

```
public class User {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Pet> pets;
}


Public class Pets {
    String id;
    String type;
}
```

How to create its Entity and DAO classes for Room Database from the following JSON?

```
{  
  "users":[  
    {  
      "id":"as123",
      "name":"John",
      "pets":[  
        {  
          "id":"p123",
          "type":"dog"
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "id":"as343",
      "name":"Mark",
      "pets":[  
        {  
          "id":"p324",
          "type":"dog"
        },
        {  
          "id":"p254",
          "type":"cat"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created the following but not sure how to create a correct column or Join these tables.

**Entity Classes**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    String id;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    String name;

    List<Pets> pets; // how to set type for Pets
}

@Entity(tableName = "pets",
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
    parentColumns = "id",
    childColumns = "userId",
    onDelete = CASCADE))
Public class Pets {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    String id;

    @Nullable
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    String type;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
    String userId; // for accessing pets of a user
}
```

**DAO classes**

```
@Dao
public interface PetsDAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(Pets pets);

    @Update
    void update(Pets... pets);

    @Delete
    void delete(Pets... pets);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pets WHERE id=:userId")
    List<Pets> getPetsForUser(final String userId);
}

@Dao
public interface UserDAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(User pets);

    @Update
    void update(User... pets);

    @Delete
    void delete(User... pets);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user)
    List<User> getAllUsers(); // should return list of users with all their pets
}
```

How can I get a `List` of users with all of their respective pets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relation so you have to create a join table:
UserPetsJoin table with the petId and userId;
Here you can find a good topic explaining you're same situation:
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Comment: I have checked it but it is confusing. Q1. Do I need to create separate POJO for GSON and separate class (Entity) for ROOM? Q2. Do I need separate DAO classes for each table or single DAO can also serve?

Comment: Q1: you can use multiple annotations in the same POJO.
Q2 : yes you have to create a DAO for each table.

Comment: That means I can use AutoValue with Room? I saw somewhere it is not supported as AutoValue does not genetrates setters.

Comment: I never used AutoValue but I've just seen that you can create a Builder pattern with it.

Comment: here I saw it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869545/android-room-persistence-library-entity-with-autovalue

Comment: Technically, this is a one-to-many relationship. "One" user has "many" pets.